# Export pie chart from ASP Classic to excel

Tags: asp-classic

I have multiple pie charts that's created using Charts.js. I have already built an Excel export to export the table from the HMTL page to Excel. Now, I would like to pass a few variables into excel and then create a pie chart from these variables, maybe using a macro. So, that when the user clicks the "Export to Excel" button everything is in the excel file. Is this even possible?

If not could I save the charts as images and insert them into the export as well as the other information?

Comment: Can you clarify 1. How you are exporting info into excel currently. 2. do you have any specific limitations in regard to your server permissions for saving files. 3. are the people you want to have this file competent (Seriously. Most solutions will not appear correctly if a user ignores the enable macros banner at the top)

Comment: Thanks for the quick Response. 1. The files are exported using. Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=fileName.xls" 2. No limitations as far as I know. 3. Most of the users are still using whiteout on iPads, so no, not competent at all.

Answer (score 0):

<s>As a simple answer, what I would say is to stick with the format that you are using to produce your report currently, only use XML instead of HTML.</s>

How this would work is you should take take the report you have currently and on the second page turn that table into a chart in excel. You can then go to excel's options and save it as an XML document. Open that document in any editor and you will need to reverse engineer it to build your XML formatted response from your page.

See here as a starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203722(v=office.11).aspx

**Edit**

The XML method won't work. Just reread the page and it specifically says:

> The following Excel features cannot be persisted in XML:
>
> Charts, OLE Objects...

So for an actual chart you will need to use a predesigned excel sheet. What you would do with this is create an excel sheet using the same table format you would be producing on the page. Then design the chart based on the columns you intend to use.

You can then insert into this file, save it to the server and subsequently send it to the client for download. See here for info on how to do that: [ASP Classsic - Insert into Excel .XLS columns or Create a Real Excel Format File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24517978/asp-classsic-insert-into-excel-xls-columns-or-create-a-real-excel-format-file).

Comment: Thanks For the quick comment. That's the approach I originally took, however, I built the charts in excel and saved them as a HTML page. When I opened the HTML file it had saved the charts as .png files and the code just uses the image files for the pie charts. However, I will try and save it as an XML file. Once again Thanks.